# Is that possible to create multiple cells in one xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I found it can create different cells with  different xibs, but I want to know is possible to create different cell in one xib? If possible, what should I can do this?

[image: here]

Here is the code, I know it is wrong code, so can you guys help me to fix it?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [imageTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ImageTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"oneImageTableViewCell"];
    [imageTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ImageTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"twoImageTableViewCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *identifier1 = @"oneImageTableViewCell";
    NSString *identifier2 = @"twoImageTableViewCell";
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        ImageTableViewCell *cell = [imageTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    } else {
        ImageTableViewCell *cell = [imageTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like you're ready to test the idea.  what happens when you run this code?

Comment: @danh It will crash with the reason Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:]

Comment: @Liearth for better solution please use prototype cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first idea would be to not do it.  But if I had to do it, I guess I'd try building cells by using the old style dequeue, and, to build the initial pool of reusable cells, by manually extracting them from the nib.

So, don't do any cell nib or cell class registration, then in cellForRowAtIndexPath...

```
NSString *identifier;
NSInteger index;
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    identifier = @"oneImageTableViewCell";
    index = 0;
} else {
    identifier = @"twoImageTableViewCell";
    index = 1;
}
UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (!cell) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = topLevelObjects[index];
}
return cell;
```

Comment: Thank you, it work.
And I just want to know what is your first idea to do it? I think that it can easy to manage different cells in one place, and I don't want to create too many different cell class in a project.

Comment: How to set outlets for multiple cells in single owner/class

Comment: @MayurKothawade I don't think I've ever tried that. I can try when I'm near a computer again in a few hours. Did you try and have a problem?  Feel free to comment here with a link to your question.

Comment: Is it working in Swift?. I tried this same thing but getting crash.. Please help this concepts in Swift. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @joelprithivi - it ought to work the same way in Swift.  Feel free to link to a question that includes details (including the text of the crash).

Comment: Working fine in Objc but not working in Swift. The crash reason is: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (customTableViewCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'.