# Load multiple uitableview cells under one xib in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know it is possible that we can load multiple uitableview cells under one xib in Objective C but is it possible also in swift?

I tried to use same logic I used in Objective C

```
var cellAuditDetails:AuditDetailsTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customTrialDetailsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AuditDetailsTableViewCell

            if indexPath.row == 0{
               if(cellAuditDetails == nil)
               {
                  cellAuditDetails = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AuditDetailsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! AuditDetailsTableViewCell;
               }
            }
            else{
                  cellAuditDetails = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AuditDetailsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[1] as! AuditDetailsTableViewCell;
}
```

[image]

But got the following error `***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier (customTrialDetailsCell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'`

Now If I use only one cell then its fine. But how do I load multiple cells under same xib? Because its irritating to take another xib for each new cell.

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34504366/4687211 ?

Comment: Why do you want to use an extra nib? You can easily create multiple different prototype cells in a table view in Interface Builder. By the way: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` returns always a non-optional cell so it will be never `nil`.

Comment: @Lu_ : I tried but this feature does not work in swift.

Comment: @Poles this is swift answer how it can not work in swift?

Comment: @Lu_ : No, Its not its an objective c answer. Please double check.

Comment: @vadian : I just don't want to congest all views and cells in one place. Besides, in my design the tableview height is small. So its hard to design two cells in one place.

Comment: @Poles Your *don't want* makes things unnecessarily more difficult. And what's the difference designing a cell in a nib or table view environment? Have you ever tried to do it?

Comment: @vadian : You are correct there is no difference. I have designed multiple cells in tableview environment one of my project. But my point is that why I can't use nib also. whereas in objective c it is possible.

Comment: It seems that you have a different implementation in Swift than your Objective C code.  In your Swift app you have registered the reuse identifier against the NIB, which is why you are getting the exception. Your objective c code doesn't do this. It loads the nib and the accesses the first or second view in the nib. If you use the objective c approach in your swift app it will work the same.

Comment: @Paulw11 : Please check my answer. Is this a correct way?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I managed to solve this problem in Swift 3. Thanks to @waris-shams. Here is the solution:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell")

     if indexPath.row == 0{
        if(cell == nil)
        {
             let cellAuditDetails:AuditDetailsTableViewCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AuditDetailsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)? [0] as! AuditDetailsTableViewCell
             cell = cellAuditDetails
         }
      }
      else{
           if(cell == nil)
           {
              let cellAuditDetails:AuditDetailsTableViewCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AuditDetailsTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)? [1] as! AuditDetailsTableViewCell
              cell = cellAuditDetails
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you distinguishing the views in your XIB (tags, custom classes, etc), then you don't even need to register the nib – all you have to do is this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellIndex = 12345
    var cellIdentifier = "MyAwesomeCell"

    // dequeue cell or, if it doesn't exist yet, create a new one from the nib
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    if !cell {
        var topLevelObjects = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyNibWithLotsOfCustomCells", owner: self, options: nil)
        var index = (topLevelObjects as NSArray).indexOfObject(passingTest: {(_ obj: Any, _ idx: Int, _ stop: Bool) -> BOOL in
                // if you distinguish the views by class
                return type(of: obj) === NSClassFromString(cellIdentifier)

                // if you distinguish the views by tag
                return (obj as! UIView).tag == cellIndex
            })
        cell = topLevelObjects[index]
    }
}
```

and one more thing to remember that use

```
dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:cellIdentifier)
```

instead of

```
dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
```

Comment: Ok. I will try it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.